# Export Test Cases including Steps & Results from Rally to TFS

Tags: tfs, export, rally, migrate, testcase

I would like to export test cases (including steps & expected results) from Rally to TFS.
As of now, i see we can export only test cases using plug in or Rally-TFS connector.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to export Test Cases with their Steps and Expected Results would be using the Excel Add-In.  You could select Test Case Step as the query type then the following columns should get you the information you are looking for:

CreationDate,ExpectedResult,Input,StepIndex,TestCase,TestCase.FormattedID,TestCase.Type,TestCase.WorkProduct

You can find more information on the Excel Add-In here:
http://help.rallydev.com/rally-add-excel

As for importing them into TFS, please note that the TFS connector does not provide support for Test Case Steps.